# Mesibo Custom UI for audio video call for ios

Tags: ios, audio, video, call, mesibo

i am implement mesibo sdk in ios its completety working fine, but i am required custom UI for videocall and audiocall in ios am not finding any document or demo custom ui of audio call and video call for ios. can you help me how i am develop custom ui of audio,video call .

Comment: Hi It's not clear what is the exact **programming** issue. What does custom UI mean (explain one example of something you want to customize)? Otherwise can't you just create your own text / graphics and apply Mesibo function to them (eg: your UI icon will trigger a `Mesibo.call` when user presses it)...

Comment: now ignore custom UI but when am install pod 'mesibo', 'mesibo-ui','mesibo-calls'